# ChromeDriver not working for Angular application - Selenium Automation

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm working on automating an Angular application. Scripts which I have implemented perfectly works for Microsoft Edge browser. But when same scripts I am running for Chrome browser after instantiating the ChromeDriver in my code Its starts giving null pointer exception.
However , code launches the application but when it comes to `driver.getTitle()`, its starts giving null pointer exception.

Chrome Version :- 103

Selenium Version :- 4.0.0-alpha-5

Code :-

```
System.out.println("Running in Chrome");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "Drivers" + File.separator + "chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions Ioptions = new ChromeOptions();
Ioptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(Ioptions);
driver.get(app_url);
driver.getTitle();
```

Exception :-

java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.optum.taskTracker.ui.stepDefinitions.Hooks.takescreenshot(Hooks.java:269)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:37)
at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:13)
at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:31)
at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaHookDefinition.execute(JavaHookDefinition.java:60)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHookIfTagsMatch(Runtime.java:223)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHooks(Runtime.java:211)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runAfterHooks(Runtime.java:205)
at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:46)
at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExecutionUnitRunner.run(ExecutionUnitRunner.java:91)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExamplesRunner.run(ExamplesRunner.java:59)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at cucumber.runtime.junit.ScenarioOutlineRunner.run(ScenarioOutlineRunner.java:53)
at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:63)
at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:18)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:70)
at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:93)
at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:37)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.run(Cucumber.java:98)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:768)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)

Comment: you have `NullPointerException at stepDefinitions.Hooks.takescreenshot(Hooks.java:269)`, not at `driver.getTitle();`, if you want help attach `takescreenshot` method

Answer (score 0):

*Selenium Version :- 4.0.0-alpha-5* is ancient now. Upgrade to current released [***Selenium Version 4.3.0***](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).

Comment: Not working with 4.3.0 version too

Comment: What error do you see? Update the question with the error tracelogs.

Comment: Updated my question with logs

Comment: _`NullPointerException`_ is in `stepDefinitions.Hooks.takescreenshot()` not at `driver.getTitle();`. Sounds to be a different question all together.